# login application with mean stack

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

how to create mean stack login page with storing and retrieval of data from mongo
I have tried using a existing link which is from a site I want the exact procedure for storing and retrieving data from database(mongo).
could anyone please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Use [meanjs.org](http://meanjs.org)'s boilerplate.. Its pretty much sorted and really good.

Has already setup login and full app structure. Its awesome.